# How to use navigation property to retrieve data over two entities with a mapping table?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have two entities, "Users" and "Systems" and a mapping table "MapUsersSystems" with UserID and SystemID. A user can have access to multiple systems, a system can be accessed by multiple users. I'm new to EF Core and not sure if my approach is correct. How do I retrieve all the systems a certain user has access to?

```
Users CurrentUser = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(b => b.PkId == System.Convert.ToInt32(UserID));

List<MapUsersSystems> systems = context.MapUsersSystems.Where(b => b.FkUser == CurrentUser.PkId).ToList();
```

At this point, I have a list of MapUsersSystems objects that I could loop over to retrieve the Systems with the Foreign Key of MapUserSystems. But I'm not sure that is the intended way of doing this. Is there a better way to get the systems a user has access to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. Just select the `System` property from the `MapUsersSystems`:

```cs
List<System> systems = 
    context.MapUsersSystems
       .Where(b => b.FkUser == CurrentUser.PkId)
       .Select(us => us.System)
       .ToList();
```

Side note: do yourself a favor and use singular words for class names and reference properties. Only collection properties should be plural. Makes your code far more self-explanatory.